# Liquibase not generating changeLog file in src/main/resources folder from existing DB in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, liquibase

I am trying to generate a change log on an existing `DB` through `Liquibase` and `Spring Boot`.

In the terminal window when I run `mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog` I can see the `XML` output of the entire change log getting generated and scrolling through but the file is not getting generated in `src/main/resources` folder even after specifying the path in the `liquibase-maven-plugin` plugin configuration in the pom.

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//person-db:6136/person-sid
spring.datasource.username=abc
spring.datasource.password=def
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

**pom.xml**

```
  <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
     <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/dbChangeLog.xml</changeLogFile>
                    <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//person-db:6136/person-sid</url>
                    <username>abc</username>
                    <password>def</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**Terminal Logs (after executing mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog command)**

```
<databaseChangeLog>
    .....
    <changeSet author="R649526 (generated)" id="1553629923684-9">
            <createTable tableName="APPL_SNDER_TRGR_CNTL" tablespace="TS_USRT_DEV_SML_DATA">
                <column name="RECEIVING_APPL_ID" type="VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)">
                    <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="SYS_C0067672"/>
                </column>
                <column name="SNDING_APPL_ID" type="VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)">
                    <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="SYS_C0067672"/>
                </column>
                <column name="RECEIVING_APPL_CHNL_ID" type="VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)">
                    <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="SYS_C0067672"/>
                </column>
                <column name="LINK_DIR_CD" type="VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)"/>
                <column name="SNDING_APPL_TRGR_NM" type="VARCHAR2(80 BYTE)">
                    <constraints nullable="false"/>
                </column>
                <column name="LAST_UPDT_TS" type="TIMESTAMP(6)">
                    <constraints nullable="false"/>
                </column>
            </createTable>
        </changeSet>
        <changeSet author="R649526 (generated)" id="1553629923684-10">
            <createTable tableName="BAT_APPL_FILE_CNTL" tablespace="TS_USRT_DEV_SML_DATA">
                <column name="APPL_ID" type="VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)">
                    <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="SYS_C0067673"/>
                </column>
                <column name="BAT_FILE_CNTL_TS" type="TIMESTAMP(6)">
                    <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="SYS_C0067673"/>
                </column>
                <column name="LINK_DIR_CD" type="VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)">
                    <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="SYS_C0067673"/>
                </column>
                <column name="BAT_FILE_NB" type="NUMBER">
                    <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="SYS_C0067673"/>
                </column>
                <column name="BAT_FILE_CRE_TS" type="TIMESTAMP(6)">
                    <constraints nullable="false"/>
                </column>
                <column name="BAT_FILE_MSG_CNT" type="NUMBER">
                    <constraints nullable="false"/>
                </column>
                <column name="BAT_FILE_PROC_TS" type="TIMESTAMP(6)"/>
                <column name="BAT_FILE_STS_CD" type="VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)">
                    <constraints nullable="false"/>
                </column>
                <column name="BAT_FILE_RJCT_RSN_TX" type="VARCHAR2(80 BYTE)"/>
                <column name="LAST_UPDT_TS" type="TIMESTAMP(6)"/>
            </createTable>
        </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: src/main/resources does not exist at runtime

Comment: You can use "/resource/log" folder to create log files. Spring also writes logs at '/tmp/Spring.log' file.

Comment: @Jens - I pointed to a folder that already exists `C:\\Logs\\dbChangeLog.xml` but still there is no file getting generated there.

Comment: @Bibek - I tried putting in `/resource/log` folder but I do not see this getting generated anywhere.

Comment: Search you file system for a file named `dbChangeLog.xml`. Maybe it got created elsewhere? Also check for exceptions in your log. When liquibase is having problems to create your changelog file there might be exceptions in your log that could help you...

Comment: @Jens - Searched for it. Found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Checked the xmldoc of the maven plugin, and it happens you have to use the parameter `<outputChangeLogFile>` instead of `<changeLogFile>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try different version of Liquibase that might help you.

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/dbChangeLog.xml</changeLogFile>
                <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//person-db:6136/person-sid</url>
                <username>abc</username>
                <password>def</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Tried different versions here `3.0.5, 3.5.5`. But no luck. The file just doesn't get generated. To me this looks like some configuration issue from my side.